# Google Sheet IMPORTXML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, urlfetch

from the [website](https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/etf/ishares-s-p-500-energy-sector-ucits-etf-usd-acc) i would export the value **7.779** from the following code using Google Sheet importxml function.

[image]

i tried with the code:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/etf/ishares-s-p-500-energy-sector-ucits-etf-usd-acc"; "//tr[@class='widget-table-row']")
```

but i get the following results:

[image]

Have you any suggestions?

Comment: The website uses JavaScript for rendering price, import xml work only with static html/xml

Comment: So how can i solve?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it seems that your expected value is retrieved from an API. And, the values are returned as JSON data. So, in your situation, how about using Google Apps Script as follows?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you want to use this as a custom function, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE()` in a cell. By this, the value is retrieved. Also, you can directly run this script with the script editor. When you directly run this script, you can see the retrieved value in the log.

```js
function SAMPLE() {
  const end = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  const start = end - 3600;
  const url = `https://api.boerse-frankfurt.de/v1/tradingview/lightweight/history/single?from=${start}&to=${end}&symbols=XETR%3AIE00B42NKQ00`;
  const obj = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  const res = obj[0].quotes.timeValuePairs.pop().value;
  console.log(res) // You can check the retrieved value in the log.
  return res;
}
```

- In the current stage, when this script is run, a value of `7.779` is obtained.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, it's work! Only one question: why did you choose 3600 as time for the end?

Comment: ＠pila pila8 Thank you for replying. About `it's work!`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Only one question: why did you choose 3600 as time for the end?`, I think that although I'm not sure whether I cannot know the detail of the specification of the API, when I tested this, in this case, it seems that various values can be used. As the default value of the request from HTML, the value of 2 days ago is used as the end date. But, in this case, the response value is large. So I used it. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @pila pila8 By the way, even when `const start = end - 3600;` is modified to `const start = end;`, the value can be retrieved. But, when `end` is not used, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.